# The expected value of the average of uniform samples is the population average

Tags: probability, proof-writing

Let $S\subseteq[0,1]$ be a finite set of $n$ elements. An experiment consists in sampling each element with probability $p$. $S_i\subseteq S$ is the sample obtained by performing the experiment the $i$-th time, and $n_i$ is the number of elements in $S_i$.

My intuition is that the expected value of the average of the elements in $S_i$ is the mean of $S$, as $S_i$ are uniform samples of $S$:

$$E\left[\frac{\sum_{v\in S_i}v}{n_i}\right] = \frac{\sum_{v\in S}v}{n},$$

where the expectation is taken over the randomness of the experiment process.

I can prove that this is the case if I assume that the cardinality of $S_i$ is $np$. The sketch of this proof is to write the expected value explicitly as a sum of all possible subsets with $np$ elements and $1/\binom n {np}$ uniform probabilities. However, I think this is not accurate because $n_i$ is a random variable in itself and I should not fix it.

I would like to know if my current proof is indeed wrong and whether someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the law of total expectation to write
$$
E\left[\frac{\sum_{v\in S_i} v}{n_i}\right] = 
\sum_{m=0}^{n} E\left[\frac{\sum_{v\in S_i} v}{n_i} \bigm\vert n_i = m\right] P\left(n_i=m\right).
$$
Now, your same proof should be able to show that
$$
E\left[\frac{\sum_{v\in S_i} v}{n_i} \bigm\vert n_i = m\right] 
= \frac{\sum_{v\in S} v}{n}.
$$
That is, you must sum over all subsets $S_i\subseteq S$ with $|S_i| = m$ to find the conditional expectation. Note that this takes care of your problem; $n_i$ is no longer random here, but constant for each $m$.

But then we have
$$\begin{split}
E\left[\frac{\sum_{v\in S_i} v}{n_i}\right] 
&= \sum_{m=0}^{n} \frac{\sum_{v\in S} v}{n} P\left(n_i=m\right)\\
&= \frac{\sum_{v\in S} v}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n} P\left(n_i=m\right)\\
&= \frac{\sum_{v\in S} v}{n}.
\end{split}$$

Comment: Right, I should have thought about the law of total expectation. Thanks @Milten!